# Oracle character encoding - specific symbols displayed incorrectly

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, nls-lang

Web-browser displays specific Norwegian symbols incorrectly.
configuration of DB:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS .,
NLS_CALENDAR GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1
NLS_SORT BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY $
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16
NLS_COMP BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS BYTE
```

Is the problem in `NLS_CHARACTERSET`?

Comment: i believe you're looking for NLS_LANG, which can be set in the init.ora file, or at the session level I believe

Comment: @tbone I've updated post. Could you see some problems in config?

Answer (score 2):

If the database hasn't been set up to use a multi-byte characterset, or a single character byteset compatible with those Norwegian characters, then nothing the client can do can fix that.

But you can try setting the environment variables and see whether it works

```
NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
export NLS_LANG
```

---

Looks like the database is set up for a US based character set. It is single byte "WE8ISO8859P1" and not aimed at Norwegian.

Modern apps (and Web browsers) generally use UTF-8 so there is going to be a loss of information when converting UTF-8 data to a single byte character set.

I think, for the long run, you'd be best off trying to get the database converted.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/toc.htm

Comment: I don't have access to this DB. So looks like it's DB admin part of work?

Comment: could you,please,check EDIT section I've added to post.Looks like the problem is in WE8ISO8859P1 param isn't it?